# First item in a List is always selected

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a list of items, I want to make it possible to navigate to the details view. However, the first element in the list is always passed to this view, what could be the problem?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var array: [Object] = [Object(id: .init(),property: 1),Object(id: .init(),property: 2),Object(id: .init(),property: 3)]
    
    @State var showAlert = false
    @State var showDetailsView = false
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List{
                ForEach(array){ item in
                    VStack{
                        Text(String(item.property))
                    }.onTapGesture(){ self.showAlert.toggle()}
                    .alert(isPresented: $showAlert){
                        Alert(title: Text("show details view?"), message: Text(""),
                              primaryButton: .default (Text("Show")) {
                                showDetailsView.toggle()
                              },
                              secondaryButton: .cancel()
                        )
                    }
                    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showDetailsView){ DetailsView(property: item.property) }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Object: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    var property: Int
}

struct DetailsView: View {
    var property: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(String(property!))
    }
}
```

I will get this result regardless of which item in the list I select:

[image: list][image: datails view]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this scenario we can pass clicked item like baton from `ForEach` to `Alert` to `FullScreen` to `Details`. And, of course, we should move corresponding modifiers out of cycle, they don't need to be applied to each row.

Here is a modified code. Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var array: [Object] = [Object(id: .init(),property: 1),Object(id: .init(),property: 2),Object(id: .init(),property: 3)]
    
    @State var alertItem: Object?
    @State var selectedItem: Object?
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List{
                ForEach(array){ item in
                    VStack{
                        Text(String(item.property))
                    }.onTapGesture(){ self.alertItem = item}
                }
            }
              .alert(item: $alertItem) { item in
                    Alert(title: Text("show details view?"), message: Text(""),
                            primaryButton: .default (Text("Show")) {
                              selectedItem = item
                            },
                            secondaryButton: .cancel()
                    )
              }
              .fullScreenCover(item: $selectedItem){ DetailsView(property: $0.property) }
        }
    }
}
```