# SwiftUI list items triggered multiple times

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have a simple nested **list** that generates **DisclosureGroup** using the parent item but when I tapped on the **Button** in the child node, it's called multiple times which includes child view initialization as well.

```
struct TopicView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var levelsListVM = LevelsViewModel()
    @State var isActive = false
    @State var levelId : Int = 0
    @State var topicId : Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(self.levelsListVM.levelsWithTopics, id:\.level ) { level in
                DisclosureGroup(
                    isExpanded: .constant(!level.isLock),
                    content: {
                        VStack {
                            ForEach(level.topics, id:\.title ) { topic in
                                Button (action: {
                                    self.levelId = level.level
                                    self.topicId = topic.id
                                    self.isActive = true
                                }, label: {
                                    ImageDisplay(imageURL: topic.imageUrl).clipShape(Circle())
                                        .background(Color.blue)
                                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                }).fullScreenCover(isPresented: self.$isActive, content: {
                                    GameTwo(level: level.level, topicId: topic.id, practiceMode: true)
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    label: {
                        HStack {
                            ImageDisplay(imageURL: level.levelImageUri).clipShape(Circle())
                                .background(Color.blue)
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                            HStack {
                                VStack {
                                    Text(level.levelName)
                                    Text("Level  0 / 2 / 3").font(.subheadline)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Demo")
    }
}
```

How Can I avoid this behavior?

FYI: I'm using **ObservedObject** and **MVVM** pattern to pass the data.

Comment: The next should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/65480211/12299030. You should not use one state for every view in list.

Comment: I figured out why this happens when swift wants to load the screen it initialize the class for each item in the forEach loop and it doesn't matter that if you tapped on the item or not. 
So I need to make sure to don't include any functionality in the target class initializer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why this happens when swift wants to load the screen it initialize the class for each item in the forEach loop and it doesn't matter that if you tapped on the item or not.

So I need to make sure to don't include any functionality in the target class initializer.

---

(Answer extracted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66012946/swiftui-list-items-triggered-multiple-times#comment116731535_66012946) comment)