# How to switch between views using @State and fullScreenCover in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode12, swiftui-environment, swiftui-state

I'm trying to figure out how to switch between views using @State and fullScreenCover in SwiftUI

I have a main view and 2 simple views (`View1` and `View2`). `View1` must open on the tap of the `"Show view 1"` button, and `View2` when typing on the `"Show view 2"` button. I also created 2 `@State` variables for this to work and initialized it with a `.View1` (`ActiveFullscreenview` enum):

```
 @State private var showFullscreenView = false
 @State private var activeFullscreenView: ActiveFullscreenView = .View1
```

The problem is that it constantly showing the `View1` even when I tap on the `Show view 2` Button.
I thought that when tapping on the button and giving the activeFullscreenView variable a value of `.View2` , it should change the variable and show the `fullScreenView`.

I supposed that it was because I called the `showFullscreenView` and it changed the variable and after that the default value was `.View1` so it didn't change it.

tried this too:

```
 self.showFullscreenView = true
 self.activeFullscreenView = .View2
```

The second assumption was that I shouldn't give this variable the initial value. But in this case it adds some additional initialisation code that is not convenient:

```
 @State private var activeFullscreenView: ActiveFullscreenView = .View1
```

Currently I have the following code that has the described issue:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {
    
    enum ActiveFullscreenView {
        case View1, View2
    }
    
    @State private var showFullscreenView = false
    @State private var activeFullscreenView: ActiveFullscreenView = .View1
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            VStack {
            
            // Button to show View 1 in FullScreen
            Button("Show view 1", action: {
                
                self.activeFullscreenView = .View1
                self.showFullscreenView = true
               
            })
            
            // Button to show View 2 in FullScreen
            Button("Show view 2", action: {
                
                self.activeFullscreenView = .View2
                self.showFullscreenView = true
               
            })
                
            }
            
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showFullscreenView) {
            
            switch self.activeFullscreenView {
            case .View1:
                
                Text("View1")
       
            case .View2:
                
                Text("View2")
             
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}

struct MainView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainView()
    }
}
```

Any help related to solving the problem appreciated. Convenient ways ways about how to achieve the same results of showing separate views using fullscreenCover appreciated.

Working in Xcode 12.4, latest iOS 14

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65480211/12299030? (you need `fullScreenCover(item:...` instead)

Comment: @Asperi hi, thanks. I tried it but got errors, couldn't implement it correctly. according to your example I tried to create a  `@State var selectedFullscreenView: ActiveFullscreenView?` , and used a `.fullScreenCover(item: $selectedFullscreenView) { _ in
              switch selectedFullscreenView {
            case .View1:  Text("View1")
            case .View2:  Text("View2")
            }}` But getting error: *Instance method 'fullScreenCover(item:onDismiss:content:)' requires that 'MainView.ActiveFullscreenView' conform to 'Identifiable'* .

Comment: You have to make `ActiveFullScreenView` `Identifiable` -- check out how I did this to `ActiveSheet` on my answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66162219/swiftui-switch-sheet-on-enum-does-not-work/66162319#66162319  Let me know if you need more

Comment: Thanks @jnpdx , your link helped a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @jnpdx who provided
[This Answer that is Similar to My problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66162219/swiftui-switch-sheet-on-enum-does-not-work/66162319#66162319) the problem is solved. Here is the code. As long as fullScreenCover and sheet are both modals, I renamed enum to ModalView:

```
struct MainView: View {
    
    // enum to decide which view to present:
    enum ModalView: String, Identifiable { // Identifiable
        
        case View1, View2
        
        var id: String {
            return self.rawValue
        }
    }
    
    @State var activeModalView : ModalView? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            VStack {
                
                // Button to show View 1
                Button("Show view 1", action: {
                    
                    self.activeModalView = .View1
                    
                })
                
                // Button to show View 2
                Button("Show view 2", action: {
                    
                    self.activeModalView = .View2
                    
                })
                
            }
            
        } // use fullScreenCover or sheet depending on your needs
        .fullScreenCover(item: $activeModalView) { activeModalValue in
            
            switch activeModalValue {
            case .View1:
                
                Text("View1")

            case .View2:
                
                Text("View2")
                
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you -- if you found it helpful and you haven't yet, you can upvote that answer I pointed you towards

Comment: @jnpdx upvoted already, thanks once again for your rapid help!!!

Comment: @jnpdx btw also checked your music and apps, great Job!! I'm also into music a little bit as a hobby, downloading some of your music apps to use in my music prod routines. Keep it up

Comment: Wow -- thank you so much for checking them out!