# Difference in using @State and @Published variables?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have three views (`ContentView`, `ChildViewA` and `ChildViewB`). Everything should work like this: from `ContentView` I go to `ChildViewA` (with using `fullScreenCover`), from there go to `ChildViewB`, in this view I tap a button and close both views `ChildViewA` and `ChildVIewB` (thanks to common `@Binding` `isPresented` variable). Also we use `@EnvironmentObject` to output some text in `ChildViewA` (because of this, there will be an error)

There are differences in behavior if we use `isPresented` (to show `fullScreenCover`) as `@State` declared in the `ContentView` or as `@Published` (from `@ObservableObject`) declared in the `ViewModel`:

**It works (we use `@State`):**

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var isPresented = false
}

class EnvObj: ObservableObject{
    @Published var foo = "test"
}

struct ContentView: View {
    //@ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    @State var isPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Open Child View A"){
            isPresented.toggle()
        }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented){ChildViewA(isPresented: $isPresented)//.environmentObject(EnvObj()) we don't have to inject @EnvironmentObject into a new environment, everything works without it because we use @State 
        }
    }
}

struct ChildViewA: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var envObj: EnvObj
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    
    @State var openChildB = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
            //No error here
            Text(envObj.foo)
            NavigationLink(destination: ChildViewB(isPresented: $isPresented)){
                Text("Open Child View B")
                
            }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ChildViewB: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var envObj: EnvObj
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Close Child View A and B"){
            isPresented = false
        }
    }
}
```

**This does not work(we use `@ObservableObject`):**

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var isPresented = false
}

class EnvObj: ObservableObject{
    @Published var foo = "test"
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    //@State var isPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Open Child View A"){
            viewModel.isPresented.toggle()
        }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $viewModel.isPresented){ChildViewA(isPresented: $viewModel.isPresented)//.environmentObject(EnvObj()) uncomment this to inject @EnvironmentObject into a new environment and everything will work
        }
    }
}

struct ChildViewA: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var envObj: EnvObj
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    
    @State var openChildB = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
            //Error here: No ObservableObject of type EnvObj found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for EnvObj may be missing as an ancestor of this view.
            Text(envObj.foo)
            NavigationLink(destination: ChildViewB(isPresented: $isPresented)){
                Text("Open Child View B")
                
            }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ChildViewB: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var envObj: EnvObj
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Close Child View A and B"){
            isPresented = false
        }
    }
}
```

As I understood the error in the case of use `@ObservableObject` is that we need to inject `@EnvironmentObject` into each new environment (`fullScreenCover` creates a new environment). So this way we should inject `@EnvironmentObject`: `.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $viewModel.isPresented){ChildViewA(isPresented: $viewModel.isPresented).environmentObject(EnvObj())`

But why is this not required in the case of `@State` variable, isn’t a new environment created?  Or I have a bug of Xcode (12.0.1)?

Comment: No, your first example crashes on iOS 14.4, Xcode 12.4. Even if for some reason it works for you it's a bug and you really shouldn't follow this path. If you declare an `@EnvironmentObject` you must inject it to the environment.

Comment: @pawello2222 So I need to update Xcode. Thanks for the answer !

Comment: You need to use `fullScreenCover(item:`, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/65480211/12299030.