# .fullScreenCover only shows first item of array .onTapGesture - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a row, that when tapped, toggles the .fullScreenCover. This all works fine - but the issue is the cover only gets passed the data from the first item in the array.

Let's say I have a row that displays 4 items from an array. When I tap on for example the third item in the row, this toggles the .fullScreenCover - but it shows the first item of the array. In retrospect, this should show the item tapped (in this case the third item).

```
struct viewOne: View{
    var allRecipes = [RecipeItem]
     @State var showRecipeModal = false
    var body : some View {
 VStack {
            self.generateRowView()
            
        }
    }
     private func generateRowView -> some View {
        return ZStack {
            ForEach(allRecipes, id: \.self) { recipe in
                self.item(image: recipe.recipeImage, title: recipe.recipeTitle)
                
            }
        }
        
    }
    func item(image: String, title: String) -> some View {
        VStack{
            WebImage(url: URL(string: image))
                .resizable()
                .frame (width: 110, height:130)
                .cornerRadius(15)
            
                HStack{
                    Text(title).bold()
                        .padding(.leading, 20)
                    Spacer()
                }
            
                .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showRecipeModal){
                    RecipeControllerModal(name: title, image: image) // << only displays first item.
                }
              
            }
        .onTapGesture {
           showRecipeModal = true
        }
     
        
    }
}
//display view One
struct RecipeFullListView: View {  
    @ObservedObject var rm = RecipeLogic()
 
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            VStack{
                Text("Recipes")
                ViewOne(allRecipes: rm.recipes) //<< provides recipes to view One
                
            }

        }
    }
}


    struct RecipeItem{
      var recipeTitle, recipeImage: String
}
```

Comment: Use instead `fullScreenCover(item:`. Here is an answer on same question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65480211/12299030.

Comment: Also using `ForEach` inside a `ZStack` will place all `item` views above each other.

Comment: Asperi to the rescue again lol Thank you! This couples with $0.parameter worked like a charm